# How to complete the gardening achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I'm trying to get the gardening achievement:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the Gardening achievement: "Destroy all the corruption in the Gardens of Hope without leaving the game." Shows 26/27 progress.]

I went through all of the Gardens of Hope (both tiers) and destroyed all the corruptions I could see. But still I am missing one. Does anyone has a clue?

The maps of the cleared areas:

[image: Screenshot of the Gardens of Hope 1st Tier]
[image: Screenshot of the Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier]

Comment: Beyond the huge barricades, there are also a lot of smaller-sprouts of corruption that are not shown on the map. Maybe we have to clear all of them too (just guessing).

Comment: Did you get the ones in the Hell Portals?  I think there's some in there.

Comment: @fbueckert, I have actuality returned to the game After I cleared the portals So I didn't have them in this play through.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got this from a [Rarity Guide article](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/2461/1/Diablo-3-Achievement-Guide---Act-IV-Challenges-/Page1.html), which is clearer...

**Gardening (10)**

Destroy all the corruption in the Gardens of Hope without leaving the game

There are 27 corruptions in the Garden of Hope. Some players have reported seeing only 26 corruptions, however this might have been a bug. There should be 27. If your quest is bugged, restart it.

You may have gotten the bugged version, or you missed one on the map.

A way to make sure that the bug doesn't happen is to destroy all the corruptions except for the last one, and wait until the achievement is updated to note that you've destroyed 26/27 corruptions (may take few minutes). And only once it's updated to 26 destroy the last one.

The big corruption growths are the ones you need to destroy. Not the small ones (They are noted on the map).

Comment: I actually had a game with 28 corruptions in it.

Comment: Lol. Well, you only need 27... so lucky you. :P

Comment: @RenoYeo, Could you put the source?

Comment: http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/2461/1/Diablo-3-Achievement-Guide---Act-IV-Challenges-/Page1.html

Comment: I actually was playing with someone else when he got the achievement and I didn't (even though I never left the game), so I can verify it's definitely bugged (or has some undocumented requirements!)

Answer (score 3):

This bugged for me the first two times.  Something I noticed was to do this SLOWLY.  I noticed when checking the achievements tab that the achievement was slow to update.  I ended up doing about 5 each time and taking a 5-10 min break in between, when I got to the last one and verified it was the last I just sat there in game for a bit until it updated to 26/27.  Killed the last growth and got the achievement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug nor a slow count, just open Light of Hope and begin the quest instead of teleport to the two places.  You get one extra corruption when u follow the story line by killing Rakanoth.

Comment: I don't think there are any near Rakanoth, at least not any that count.

Comment: You don't need to think. Just do it, there is one in the Library of Fate when u walk in to meet rakanoth